# GROUP BY not working well

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i have a table with:

```
id_order | id_order_history | date_add
```

With this query i can get all orders that have `id_order_history = 3` (in preparation)

```
    SELECT 
        `oh`.`id_order`
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX( `date_add` ) AS date_add
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_history`
        GROUP BY `id_order`
    ) AS h
    INNER JOIN 
        '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_history AS oh 
    ON 
        `h`.`date_add` = `oh`.`date_add`
    INNER JOIN 
        '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders AS o
    ON 
        `oh`.`id_order` = `o`.`id_order`';

    $sql .= 'WHERE
        oh.`id_order_state` = '.$status.''; 
    $sql .= ' AND  
        oh.date_add >= "'.$start.'"';
    $sql .= ' AND  
        oh.date_add <= "'.$end.'"
    ORDER BY 
        `oh`.`id_order` ASC
```

The problem is that for some order the `SELECT MAX` don't get the correct value of `date_add`

```
id_order | id_order_history | date_add

1        | 5                | 25-09-2014 18:07:59 ---> this is the correct value
1        | 4                | 25-09-2014 18:07:51
1        | 3                | 25-09-2014 18:06:42 ---> but query return this
```

If I add on date 1 second (18:06:43) the query return the correct value `25-09-2014 18:07:59`

I just can not figure out how to solve the problem.

I have read around that sometimes `GROUP BY` takes results higgledy-piggledy ...

how can I fix it?

Comment: creating a SQL fiddle would be great...

Comment: What do you intend for "foreign key"? Can you give me an example?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. Finally, it would be much easier for us to follow if you removed the PHP entirely for the time being.

Comment: You query does not makes sense.  It is using tables (`orders`) that seem unnecessary, it doesn't use the table you mention in the beginning.  Fix the question by including sample data as well as the desired results.

Comment: You are right, table orders is unnecessary, then i deleted the INNER JOIN but the result not change, only for some orders not return the correct value 25-09-2014 18:07:59 but the first 25-09-2014 18:06:42 that is not the MAX

Answer (score 0):

Convert your column `date_add` to a ISO datetimestring and/or use TO_SECONDS (see [MySQL doc here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds))

```
 ...( SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TO_SECONDS(`date_add`)) ) AS date_add
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_history`
    GROUP BY `id_order` ) AS h
```

Comment: FUNCTION TO_SECONDS does not exist :(

Comment: see provided link in answer

Comment: I tried with TIME_TO_SEC but the reseult is not what i want. I want to know why for only few date, the result is not correct because i think the query is correct. If i add only one second in the date where i receive wrong result, the result return correct.

Comment: ISO Format is YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Mysql might not be able to identifiy your Format so convert it: ... MAX( STR_TO_DATE(date_add, '%d-%m-%Y %k:%i:%s')) ...

Comment: The result is the same, not get the correct value 25-09-2014 18:07:59 but the first 25-09-2014 18:06:42 that is not the MAX

Comment: What datatype has your `date_add` column?